# Diffraction grating electron velocity problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, electrons, diffraction

> Suppose that visible light incident on a diffraction grating with slit distance (space) of $0.01*10^{-3}$ has the first max at the angle of $3.6^\circ$ from the central peak. Suppose electrons can be diffracted with this same grating, which velocity of the electron would create the same diffraction pattern as this visible light?

I am thinking of using equations like $d\sin(\theta) = m\lambda$, but I am not sure where the angle comes into play here.

Obviously,

$(0.01\ \mathrm{mm})(\sin(3.6^\circ)) = m\lambda$, but this doesn't help much?

Comment: Use the data for light to find the wavelength of the light and then use that wavelength to find the speed of the electrons.

Answer (score 1):

First find the wavelength of light which corresponds to the OP, by solving the diffraction formula: $mλ = d \sin(θ)$.

The corresponding wavelength of the electrons impinging upon the sample is given by the de Broglie relationship: $\lambda  = hp = h\gamma m_e \beta $c ; where the symbols have the usual meanings:

$h$ is Planck's constant,

$c$ is the speed of light,

$m_e$ is the electron mass,

$\beta =v/c$, the speed, relative to the speed of light,

$\gamma={(1-\beta ^2)}^{-1/2}$, the Lorentz factor.

You have to invert this formula to find the velocity of the electron, $v$.
$$\beta = v/c={(1-\gamma ^2)}^{1/2}$$

I expect that $\gamma $ is very close to unity (very non-relativistic), so you can compare by using $p=0.5 m_e v^2$.

Comment: So are you saying that if you fire electrons at different speeds you will get different wavelengths and therefore different patterns on the detection screen?

Comment: @BillAlsept: the wavelength certainly depends upon the speed; this is inherent in the de Broglie formula.  Changes in wavelength determine the relative scale of the diffraction pattern, and if the wavelength is too large or small, the pattern itself will be affected.  For example, the wavelength of UV light is too large for atomic diffraction, but as you go deeper, into the x-rays, diffraction patterns begin to appear.  Varying the voltage will send you through the effects.